# "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl Ch 10. undefined method `rest_digest=' for #<User:0x007f3c04f08e20>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help. The problem is when I try submitting an email to reset a password, I get the following error.

[image: NoMethodError in PasswordResetsController#create]

**Application trace gives the following**

```
app/models/user.rb:57:in `create_reset_digest'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/jhl+HQLT42IZLH2ashW6y2fpSiUY+htnOSq4oQPeUTrkHDbaj2IvLYEmt5209E7BJV07nJK/1PH+lE1CkUgUw==",
 "password_reset"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

**Framework trace:**

```
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:238:in `update_attribute'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Full Trace**

```
app/models/user.rb:57:in `create_reset_digest'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:8:in `create'
activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:238:in `update_attribute'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wrote `"rest_digest`", should be `"reset_digest"`

Answer (score 1):

May be you wanted to assign a value to the `reset_digest` attribute and not `rest_digest` (note the typo).